# unable to autowire KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties bean in Spring cloud stream

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

i'm using spring cloud steam kafka and trying to implement a custom error handling by creating a bean of `ListenerContainerCustomizer`.

the problem is to create this bean I need `KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties` bean which is created inside the spring cloud steam application context (found it after debugging), so I'm getting `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

is there a way to access this bean ? or any other workaround ?

I'm using spring boot 2.5.13

spring cloud 2020.0.5

spring cloud stream 3.1.6

Comment: There was some recent work done which could possibly resolve you issue, but you need to upgrade to the latest version of s-c-stream which is 3.2.5. yOu are using a very old and not supported version of s-c-stream. Take Spring Cloud 2021.0.4

Comment: It is not clear why you need `KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties` in your application. If you are just trying to provide a simple `ListenerContainerCustomizer` bean, then you don't really need the properties (unless you have some advanced use cases). Here is an example that might be related: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_handling_deserialization_errors_with_dlq

Comment: If you could provide us with a small reproducible sample, then we maybe able to triage the issue further. Thanks!

Comment: i'm using a custom error handling with DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer, and i need the producer configuration from the binding by using kafkaBinderConfigurationProperties.mergedProducerConfiguration() instead of duplicating the producer configuration in the dlq config